# Configuring glassfish server / application correctly to point to different schemes

Tags: java, mysql, glassfish-4

Ive built an application that running on a glassfish server, currently i have one scheme that its pointing to. What is the best way configure my application / glassfish server so that i have one url like www.example.co.uk/ but after the forward flash it point to different mysql scheme. Example, using the same application i would like to achieve this.

Www.example.co.uk/test1 
This will point to scheme test1 after youve logged in

Www.example.co.uk/test2
This will point to scheme test2 after youve logged in

Do i set up different domains? Do i make changes to my application. Any help would be great.

Thanks